# Which areas of artificial intelligence are used to guess data?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, game-engine

I am developing a computer baseball game based on statistics. I would like to use artificial intelligence for the batters to determine which pitch is coming, and if the batter guesses correctly he will get a hit. I think that AI would be a good choice for such feature, but I don't know much about the subject. In the game the pitcher will also try to guess which pitch the batter can't hit.

Each pitcher will have 5 pitches (it could be more or less, but 5 will be the average).

I am looking forward to learn how to implement such features using artificial intelligence, and I would like to know which areas are the ones that can solve these problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Bayesian statistics are your best bet.

All baseball statistics are statistical priors in Bayes-speak.  You can start developing a model based on those.

It won't be easy, unless you have some background.  I'd recommend looking at "Doing Bayesian Data Analysis" by John K. Kruschke.

Comment: "Several different areas"?  What do you mean?  Where did you learn that?  It's one profound formula: p(x)*p(y|x) = p(y)*p(x|y).

Comment: The question itself isn't bad; it was the comment and admitting that it was bullsh!t that put me off.  I have no idea whether anyone else will bother to answer.  I'm not Nostredamus.